# What is a power clean called in German?

Tags: single-word-request, english-to-german

The barbell exercise called *power clean* is similar to a regular clean (*umsetzen*), but caught higher. What is it called in German?

See also: [a video of a power clean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TlbDQUWs0s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [body-building forum](http://www.bodybuilding-treff.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=35327) it is called

> Kraftumsetzen

According to another [forum](http://forum.golfforum.de/f.cfm?id=497810&r=threadview&t=3835874&pg=1) it is:

> Standumsetzen

But probably you do nothing wrong when using the English term. It looks like it is a technical expression which does not need to be translated. It should be well understood (by body-builders) and avoid misunderstandings because of the ambiguity in the German translations.